# How can i insert a string generated in c# code into xaml button?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I am trying to create an offline password manager. There is a function which should generate a password and put it into an entry that is supposed to hold that data. Right now i am struggling to insert a result of generating method from c# code, into xaml button.

I've tried creating an entry within c# code, and assigning a text property to it. 1st thing is i am not sure if that's the right way. 2nd thing is i have no clue what else can i do in order to solve this issue.

```
//this is the generating button in app
void OnGenerateClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var passwordEntry = new Entry();
    passwordEntry.SetBinding(Entry.TextProperty, "Haslo");

    bool includeLowercase = true;
    bool includeUppercase = true;
    bool includeNumeric = true;
    bool includeSpecial = true;
    bool includeSpaces = false;
    int lengthOfPassword = 12;
    string password = 
        PasswordGeneration.GeneratePassword(includeLowercase, includeUppercase, 
        includeNumeric, includeSpecial, includeSpaces, lengthOfPassword);
    var Haslo = new Entry { Text = password }; 
    // here i've tried to assign the text property to the entry 
    //  "Haslo" but unfortunately it's not working.
}
```

XAML:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="OpassV1.Widoki.ServicePage">
    <StackLayout Margin="20" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
        <Label Text="Nazwa" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Nazwa}" /> 
        <Label Text="Hasło"/>
        <Entry x:Name="Haslo" Text="{Binding Haslo}"/>
        <Button Text="Genruj hasło" Clicked="OnGenerateClicked" /> 
        <Button Text="Zapisz" Clicked="OnSaveClicked" />
        <Button Text="Usuń" Clicked="OnDeleteClicked" />
        <Button Text="Anuluj" Clicked="OnCancelClicked" />
        </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I'd like to display generated password in entry with "Binding Nazwa" after clicking generate button "OnGenerateClicked"

I'm grateful for all the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this creates a NEW instance of entry

```
var Haslo = new Entry { Text = password };
```

you want to use the existing Entry instance that you created in your XAML.  Any element in your XAML that has a `x:Name` property should be accessible by name in your code-behind

```
Haslo.Text = password;
```

Comment: Thank You! I forgot about that :)